# Is there a way to solve UVA 417 mathematically?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve [UVA 417](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=358), but I'm unable to do so. All the solutions that I have seen first generate all the possible values, store them in a map and then search to find the required string. This seems quite inelegant to me. Isn't there a way to solve this mathematically?

Consider the input "abc".
If the condition that every subsequent character should be greater than the present wasn't imposed, we could solve it by simply calculating 1*26^2 +2*26^1 + 3*26^0. Isn't there a way to solve the original question in a similar manner?

I'm including the code for the existing solution I found online:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

map<string, int> M;

void generate_positions(){
    queue<string> Q;
    for(char c='a';c<='z';c++) Q.push(string(1,c));

    string s;

    int cont=1;

    while(!Q.empty()){
        s=Q.front();
        Q.pop();

        M[s]=cont;
        cont++;

        if(s.size()==5) continue;

        for(char c=s[s.size()-1]+1;c<='z';c++) Q.push(s+c);
    }
}

int main(){
    generate_positions();

    string s;
    map<string, int> :: iterator it;

    while(cin>>s){
        it=M.find(s);
        if(it==M.end()) cout<<0<<endl;
        else cout<<it->second<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: include the problem statement here.

Comment: Please describe more of your own thoughts. The shown code is a solution but in no way what you are asking for. Please demonstrate some own research or thought effort.

Comment: *"Isn't there a way to solve this mathematically?"* Yes. There are 26 1-letter words, `25 + 24 + ... + 2 + 1` 2-letters words (so `25 * 13`). once you got the formula for N-letter word, you can "advance by digit".

Comment: There is an error in the statement of the problem at OP’s link. It requests the position of each word in “the alphabetized list of words” and then shows a list that places “ab” after “z”. This is not most people’s understanding of [alphabetized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order). It seems to sort first by length, then by alphabetical order.

Comment: Advancing a bit on @Jarod42's path: Consider the number of all words containing each letter at most once. For arbitrary `N`, there are `26 * 25 * ... * (27 - N)` such words. All words having the same letters are equivalent (one of is valid, the others discarded), so we end up in the famous [binominal coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) for `N`-letter words.

Comment: …Well, in just two months I\`m finally finished =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 1. TL/DR:

Let`s define an alphabet **A = {a, b, c, … z}** and its bijective alphabet **A' = {1, 2, 3, … 26}**. **|A| = |A'| = 26**.

Then let **w** denote the word consisting of characters **w<sub>0</sub>, w<sub>1</sub>, … w<sub>|w|–1</sub> ∈ A'**, in the following order:

**w = w<sub>|w|–1</sub> … w<sub>1</sub>w<sub>0</sub>**, where **|w|** denotes the word length in characters.

Now, the [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) **P(w): (A')<sup>|A'|</sup> → ℕ** that transforms the word **w, |w| ≤ |A'|**, to its position is as follows:

[image]

Transliterating **w<sub>k</sub>** to **A'** from **A** is up to the user.

## 2. Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long bin26(long n, long k) {
    static const char nprm[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31};
    long root = (long)sqrt(n), coef[sizeof(nprm) / sizeof(*nprm)] = {0};
    long indx, iter, prod, curr, prev, ncur, kcur;

    if ((n <= 0) || ((k = (k > n / 2)? n - k : k) <= 0))
        return (n > 0) && (k >= 0);
    for (indx = iter = 0; (curr = (long)nprm[iter++]) <= n; )
        if (curr > n - k)
            coef[indx++] = curr;
        else if (curr <= n / 2) {
            if (curr > root) {
                if ((n % curr) < (k % curr))
                    coef[indx++] = curr;
                continue;
            }
            for (ncur = n, kcur = k, prod = 1, prev = 0; ncur > 0; ) {
                if ((prev = ((ncur % curr) < (kcur % curr + prev))? 1 : 0))
                    prod *= curr;
                ncur /= curr;
                kcur /= curr;
            }
            if (prod > 1)
                coef[indx++] = prod;
        }
    for (iter = 1; indx; iter *= coef[--indx]);
    return iter;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const long size = 26;
    long retn, lstr, iter;

    for (--argc; argc > 0; argc--) {
        for (iter = lstr = 0; argv[argc][lstr]; iter = argv[argc][lstr++])
            if (iter >= argv[argc][lstr]) {
                lstr = 0;
                break;
            }
        for (--lstr, iter = retn = 0; iter <= lstr; iter++)
            retn += bin26(size, iter + 1)
                 -  bin26(size - argv[argc][lstr - iter] + 'a' - 1, iter + 1);
        printf("P(%s) = %ld\n", argv[argc], retn);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## 3. Explanation:

Without loss of generality let`s first limit the alphabet size and the word length to smaller values and try to visualize the problem.

Let **|A'| = 6, |w| = 3**. The full word list is shown below:

```
 k n                        [ |  ]  be  →  14            [ | ] acf  →  28
[1|1]   a  →   1            [ |  ]  bf  →  15            [ | ] ade  →  29
[ |1]   b  →   2            [ | 3]  cd  →  16            [ | ] adf  →  30
[ |1]   c  →   3            [ |  ]  ce  →  17            [ | ] aef  →  31
[ |1]   d  →   4            [ |  ]  cf  →  18            [ |6] bcd  →  32
[ |1]   e  →   5            [ | 2]  de  →  19            [ | ] bce  →  33
[ |1]   f  →   6            [ |  ]  df  →  20            [ | ] bcf  →  34
[2|5]  ab  →   7            [ | 1]  ef  →  21            [ | ] bde  →  35
[ | ]  ac  →   8            [3|10] abc  →  22            [ | ] bdf  →  36
[ | ]  ad  →   9            [ |  ] abd  →  23            [ | ] bef  →  37
[ | ]  ae  →  10            [ |  ] abe  →  24            [ |3] cde  →  38
[ | ]  af  →  11            [ |  ] abf  →  25            [ | ] cdf  →  39
[ |4]  bc  →  12            [ |  ] acd  →  26            [ | ] cef  →  40
[ | ]  bd  →  13            [ |  ] ace  →  27            [ |1] def  →  41
```

The left number in brackets (let`s call it **k**) shows how many letters there are in the corresponding word and those underneath it. The right number (**n**), in its turn, shows in how many consecutive words the first letter remains unchanged.

Obviously enough, when **k** changes, so does the law which the subsequent **n**-s follow. It`s quite easy to discern the pattern: when **k** equals some **K**, its corresponding **n**-s are nothing but consecutively shortening «tails» of a word stack corresponding to **K–1**, prepended with a new letter. The amount by which the «tail» gets shortened at the next iteration **t+1**, compared to the current one, **t** (both iterations within **K**), equals the largest **n** in the remaining «tail» left here from **K–1**-th stack.

Let`s call the height of **k**-th stack **H<sub>k</sub>**. Let`s also call **t**-th **n** in a row, belonging to **k**-th stack, **n<sub>k</sub><sup>t</sup>** (naturally, **t** numbering is local to each **k**; e.g. **n<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>** is in general not the same as **n<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>**). On top of that, let`s make **t**-s go backwards (it`s a stack anyway), so in the above example **n<sub>3</sub><sup>4</sup> = 10**, **n<sub>3</sub><sup>3</sup> = 6**, **n<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> = 3**, **n<sub>3</sub><sup>1</sup> = 1**.

According to the previous observations and conventions,

[image]

From here it`s apparent that **H<sub>k–1</sub> = n<sub>k</sub><sup>|n<sub>k</sub>|+1</sup>** (forgetting for a moment that **{n<sub>k</sub>}** doesn`t actually contain the **|n<sub>k</sub>|+1**-th element). This directly leads to the definition of **H<sub>k</sub>(n)** from **[2]**:

[image]

Proceeding to the proof of the connection between **H<sub>k</sub>(n)** and [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) stated in **[3]**.

First, the basic identity (a.k.a. [Pascal`s Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)):

[image]

From the Pascal`s Rule the following can be derived:

[image]

Observant readers might have already noticed that:

[image]

Fine, that covers **H<sub>0</sub>(n)** and **H<sub>1</sub>(n)**. Let`s prove the rest by induction.

[image]

With **[3]** proven, the only thing left to derive **[4]** is to introduce **P(w)** and express it in terms of **H**-s.

For a certain word **w**, obtaining its position **P(w)** in the word list means finding the height of the stack of words superadjacent to **w**.

Finding **P<sub>1</sub>(w)**, the first approximation of **P(w)**, involves adding together the heights of sub-stacks for all **1 ≤ k ≤ |w|**:

```
 ...
|w–2|
---------
|w–1|
|w–1|
|w–1|
|w–1|
|w–1|
|w–1|
---------
| w |
| w |<--- P(w)
| w |
| w |
| w |
-----<--- P₁(w)
|w+1|
 ...
```

According to **[5]**,

[image]

Why not **1 ≤ k < |w|**? Simply because there already is a method to compute stack «tail» heights, but nothing of the sort has been devised for «heads». So, to refine the approximation the **H<sub>|w|</sub>** stack shall be divided in two at the position of **w**, and the height of its newfound «tail» is to be subtracted from the approximation.

Okay, let`s start from the stack bottom and go up. Whenever **w** equals the last word in **H<sub>|w|</sub>** stack, **P<sub>1</sub>(w)** does not need to be adjusted at all and thus equals **P(w)**.

The word that occupies the place being discussed consists of the following characters: **W<sub>|w|–1</sub>W<sub>|w|–2</sub>…W<sub>1</sub>W<sub>0</sub>**, where **W<sub>i</sub> = A'<sub>|A'|–i</sub>** — e.g. **(22)(23)(24)(25)(26)** for **H<sub>5</sub>** stack over the original **A'** (or simply **vwxyz** when transliterated to **A**). The main thing to consider here is that for all **|w|** in **H<sub>|w|</sub>**, **W<sub>0</sub>** always equals the last letter of the alphabet, **W<sub>1</sub>** equals the one which is second-to-last, etc.

Well. Now what changes if the target word is second-to-last in **H<sub>|w|</sub>**? Quite trivially, **P<sub>1</sub>(w)** gets adjusted by **–1**. Third-to-last word needs to be adjusted by **–2**, and so on until **W<sub>0</sub>** runs out of permitted letters, i.e. gets less or equal to **W<sub>1</sub>** (or to **1** if there is no **W<sub>1</sub>**). Let`s call this adjustment value **P<sub>2</sub>(w): P(w) = P<sub>1</sub>(w) – P<sub>2</sub>(w)**. For **|w| = 1**, the equation can be rewritten as follows: **P(w) = P<sub>1</sub>(w) – (|A'| – w<sub>0</sub>)**.

**W<sub>0</sub>** differing from **A'<sub>|A'|</sub>** has been covered. What about **W<sub>1</sub>** and others? Before subtracting from **W<sub>0</sub>** let`s first assume that it equals **A'<sub>|A'|</sub>**. In this case it becomes apparent that adjusting **P<sub>1</sub>(w)** for **W<sub>1</sub>** is equivalent to subtracting the corresponding «tail» of the **H<sub>2</sub>** stack, i.e. for **|w| = 2**, **P(w) = P<sub>1</sub>(w) – ((|A'| – w<sub>0</sub>) + H<sub>2</sub>((|A'| – 1) – w<sub>1</sub>))**. The minuend **(|A'| – 1)** is used instead of **|A'|** because, as stated earlier, the maximum possible value of **W<sub>1</sub>** equals **A'<sub>|A'|–1</sub> = |A'| – 1**. The same rule applies to **W<sub>2</sub>** (**H<sub>3</sub>** stack, **H<sub>3</sub>((|A'| – 2) – w<sub>2</sub>)**) and all other characters by induction.

Taking into consideration the fact that **(|A'| – w<sub>0</sub>) = H<sub>1</sub>(|A'| – w<sub>0</sub>)**,

[image]

which, considering that **P(w) = P<sub>1</sub>(w) – P<sub>2</sub>(w)**, coupled with **[6]**, finally leads to **[4]**.

Answer (score 0):

Since "a way to solve this mathematically" was requested, I provide a pseudo-algorithm.

As already mentioned, we cannot use something like "1*26^2 +2*26^1 + 3*26^0" for input "abc". However, this will be the starting point.

From this number we shall subtract the number of combinations which are not allowed (e.g. "ba"), being careful not to subtract twice ("ba" and "bba" count as 1).

The entire idea is that we can "easily" calculate how many letter sequences are not valid, rather than how many are valid. The calculation is done position by position (letter by letter).